# how to return web3 instance from nodejs to ui

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I want to return a web3 instance that contains provider object. I want to return that object to UI so that i can use that web3 instance in UI. Is this possible to achieve?
I tried converting the web3 to JSON.stringify(web3) but throwing error cannot convert circular objects to string.

here is my nodejs code

```
    const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'dress steel phrase album average asd dd room exile web eree cause',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/I7P2ErGiQjuq4jNp41OE',
  );

  web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

I would like to return web3 instance to UI from node like this

```
app.get('/getWeb3', async (req, res) => {

  console.log('web3 instance', web3);

  res.json( JSON.stringify(web3)); // this is throwing error.
})
```

I have tried using third party libraries to convert object to json like warp library but still facing issues. Any suggestions will be helpful to me. Thanks

Comment: What is the error when you try to `stringify` the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a `web3` instance, that doesn't make much sense, since you can get a `web3` instance directly on the client side.

Usually on the client side, you use [Metamask](https://metamask.io/), that will allow you to interact with the Ethereum network without running a full node.

**client side**

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
// Interact with your contract
const Contract = web3.eth.contract(ABI);
const contract = Contract.at('address'); 

contract.someMethod((err, res) => console.log(res));
```

Now the user will interact with the Ethereum network, using it's own address and keys, instead of using your private keys, which is what you were trying to do.

The `web3` instance on the server must remain private, and not be exposed to the client.

Instead of trying to send the instance to the client, why don't you tell us what are you trying to do with that instance, which is the actual question that needs to be solved.

Comment: Marcos Thanks for your reply. I tried calling web3 instance in the client side only but when i deploy the app into prod it is https and not accepting http requests getting mixed content error. Thats y i was thinking to write a nodejs api call and return web3 instance.

Comment: Show how are you instantiating web3 on the client. Is your web http?

Comment: yes the same way which i mentioned in the above code.